# ionice 'idle' not having the expected effects

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler

We're working with a reasonably busy web server. We wanted to use rsync to do some data-moving which was clearly going to hammer the magnetic disk, so we used `ionice` to put the rsync process in the idle class. The queues for both disks on the system (SSD+HDD) are set to use the CFQ scheduler.
The result... was that the disk was absolutely hammered and the website performance was appalling.

I've done some digging to see if any tuning might help with this.
The man page for `ionice` says:

```
Idle: A program running with idle I/O priority will only get disk time
when no other program has asked for disk I/O for a defined grace period.
The impact of an idle I/O process on normal system activity should be zero.
```

This "defined grace period" is not clearly explained anywhere I can find with the help of Google. One posting suggest that it's the value of `fifo_expire_async` but I can't find any real support for this.

However, on our system, both `fifo_expire_async` and `fifo_expire_sync` are set sufficiently long (250ms, 125ms, which are the defaults) that the idle class should actually get NO disk bandwidth at all. Even if the person who believes that the grace period is set by `fifo_expire_async` is plain wrong, there's not a lot of wiggle-room in the statement "The impact of an idle I/O process on normal system activity should be zero".

Clearly this is not what's happening on our machine so I am wondering if CFQ+idle is simply broken.

Has anyone managed to get it to work? Tips greatly appreciated!

**Update:**
I've done some more testing today. I wrote a small Python app to read random sectors from all over the disk with short sleeps in between. I ran a copy of this without ionice and set it up to perform around 30 reads per second. I then ran a second copy of the app with various `ionice` classes to see if the idle class did what it said on the box. I saw *no difference at all* between the results when I used classes 1, 2, 3 (real-time, best-effort, idle). This, despite the fact that I'm now absolutely certain that the disk was busy.
<strike>Thus, I'm now certain that - at least for our setup - CFQ+idle does not work.</strike> [see Update 2 below - it's not so much "does not work" as "does not work as expected"...]

Comments still very welcome!

**Update 2:**
More poking about today. Discovered that when I push the I/O rate up dramatically, the idle-class processes DO in fact start to become starved. In my testing, this happened at I/O rates hugely higher than I had expected - basically hundreds of I/Os per second. I'm still trying to work out what the tuning parameters do...

I also discovered the rather important fact that async disk writes aren't included at all in the I/O prioritisation system! The `ionice` manpage I quoted above makes no reference to that fact, but the manpage for the syscall `ioprio_set()` helpfully states:

> I/O priorities are supported for reads and for synchronous (O_DIRECT,
>   O_SYNC) writes.  I/O priorities are not supported for asynchronous
>   writes because they are issued outside the context of the program
>   dirtying the memory, and thus program-specific priorities do not
>   apply.

This pretty significantly changes the way I was approaching the performance issues and I will be proposing an update for the `ionice` manpage.

Some more info on kernel and iosched settings (sdb is the HDD):

```
Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1 (2017-12-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
/etc/debian_version = 9.3

(cd /sys/block/sdb/queue/iosched; grep . *)
back_seek_max:16384
back_seek_penalty:2
fifo_expire_async:250
fifo_expire_sync:125
group_idle:8
group_idle_us:8000
low_latency:1
quantum:8
slice_async:40
slice_async_rq:2
slice_async_us:40000
slice_idle:8
slice_idle_us:8000
slice_sync:100
slice_sync_us:100000
target_latency:300
target_latency_us:300000
```

Comment: Have you tried with low values for `slice_async` and `slice_async`? I think that once the idle priority class process gets to use the disk, it will keep going for `slice_sync` (read) or `slice_async` (write) despite the fact that then another higher priority process wants to use the disk. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41831/20336 for details. I'd try `slice_async:40`, `slice_sync:80` and `fifo_expire_async:1000`. Depending on HDD, `group_idle:0` and `slice_idle:3` (or 4-5) might be okay, too.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the only opportunity to solve your problem is using CGroup v2 (kernel v. 4.5 or newer). Please see the following article:

https://andrestc.com/post/cgroups-io/

Also please note, that you may use the systemd's wrappers to configure CGroup limits on per-service basis:

http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/resources.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your answer to include the necessary narrative within the answer text rather than just via links, since StackOverflow is a Q&A knowledge base and links may or may not be permanent. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the cgroup solution can only limit the bandwidth to some predefined value. Is that right? If so, do you agree that this is not really satisfactory? The point of an 'idle' class should be to use all available bandwidth if no one else needs it, not be limited to a preset value...

Answer (score 1):

Add nocache to that and you're set (you can join it with ionice and nice):
https://github.com/Feh/nocache

On Ubuntu install with:
apt install nocache

It simply omits cache on IO and thanks to that other processes won't starve when the cache is flushed.
It's like calling the commands with O_DIRECT, so now you can limit the IO for example with:

```
systemd-run --scope -q --nice=19 -p BlockIOAccounting=true -p BlockIOWeight=10 -p "BlockIOWriteBandwidth=/dev/sda 10M" nocache youroperation_here
```

I usually use it with:

```
nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 nocache youroperation_here
```